# How do I configure/secure LAMP stack on Fedora 37 without permissive SELinux confguration?

Tags: permissions, fedora, lamp, selinux

I've installed all the LAMP components (Apache, MySQL, and PHP) on Fedora 37, but for now I haven't changed my SELinux configuration from enforcing to permissive because I don't know what problems this would cause if there's malware or something else askew.

Naturally, even with the necessary sudo permissions, enforcing configurations in SELinux won't allow me to change or configure any of these programs.

While I did come across the chcon commands for SELinux here: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/07/chcon-command-examples/ , it is not clear to me that any of these commands address my concerns. Are there any specific commands or other paths I can take to avoid a permissive configuration in SELinux?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

TEMPORARILY turning off selinux setenforce 0 to disable, setenforce 1 to reenable) can be useful in seeing if the problem is selinux related.

Looking at /var/log/audit.log can also show if the problem is selinux related.

If it is Selinux related, copying the lines from the log file to another file and running audit2allow across that file can generate instructions you can apply to fix the issue.

Bear in mind - very much reading between the lines, running SELinux if you are not a proficient systems administrator may be counterproductive in the early stages.  Focussing on simpler best practices - like firewalls, principles of least access and logging, monitoring and strong backups may be a better way of keeping your system secure unless you are running servers at elevated risk of being attacked compared with most.  Its worth bearing in mind that many (even server) distros do not use SeLinux and do not have enhanced prorections turned on by default.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. You would be right in that this is mostly new to me and I'm not an experienced systems administrator.

Answer (score 1):

apache and php-fpm will run with `httpd_t` type.
There is 3 interesting type you can set to your files and folder that `httpd_t` has the permission to access: `httpd_sys_content_t` (read-only), `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` (read and write) and `httpd_log_t` (can also be accessed by logrotate for example).

You might then want to allow read only for some folders and files, read write for storage / cache, and log for logs.
If your website is in /opt/website, it would be something like this (example for laravel):

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/opt/website/(public|resources|vendor)(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/opt/website/storage(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/opt/website/storage/logs(/.*)?"
restorecon -RF /opt/website
```

Also, if you are using a TCP socket for php-fpm to communicate with your db and it is not working, you could need to allow `httpd_t` to do so with `setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1 -P`.

If you need apache to listen on an exotic port like 12345, you can add it with `semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 12345`

If you use php-opcache, you will also need `setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1`

You shouldn't need anything else selinux related for your lamp stack to work, but don't forget to set permissions and open the Firewall.